# How to identify the right road using postgres and postgis

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I want to identify a road at particular point of intrest using post gis.

### Example

Input String : 16th cross near xyz mall.

### Problem I am facing

As there will be many "16th cross roads" in the map , how do I identify the "16th cross near xyz mall"

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. I think you might need to add a bit more information. Your question is not clear as it stands.

Comment: Thanks @JohnBarça , You got my question ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know your data. A template could look like:

```
select st_distance(mall.geom, roads.geom) as dist 
from roads, mall
where roads.name = '16th cross' AND mall.name = 'xyz' 
order by dist
limit 1
```